# DataGrid rows are changing colors when scrolling

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create a datagrid tha shows values that have different timespans and due to what value a column in the row has the whole row changes color. I first tried to use `DataGrid_LoadingRow` And the values changed so I used a different approach but the same problem exist.

**C#**

```
MainDataGrid.ItemsSource = FileDifferences;

foreach (DataGridRow row in CreateRowsFromDataGrid(MainDataGrid))
{
    var File = row.DataContext as FileDifference;

    if (File.Time_Difference.TotalSeconds < 5.5)
    {
        // Nothing happens here
    }
    else if (File.Time_Difference.TotalSeconds < 10.5)
    {
        row.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
    }
    else if (File.Time_Difference.TotalSeconds < 20.5)
    {
        row.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
    }
    else if (File.Time_Difference.TotalSeconds >= 20.5)
    {
        row.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    }
}
```

```
private List<DataGridRow> CreateRowsFromDataGrid(DataGrid dg)
{
    List<DataGridRow> randomRowTesting = new List<DataGridRow>();
    for (int i = 0; i < dg.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
        if (row == null)
        {
            dg.UpdateLayout();
            dg.ScrollIntoView(dg.Items[i]);
            row = (DataGridRow)dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
        }

        dg.ScrollIntoView(dg.Items[0]);
        randomRowTesting.Add(row);
    }

    return randomRowTesting;
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT:**
So what my problem is is that the color is moving to a different row that shouldn't be colored when I'm scrolling and it keeps on moving to random rows when I scroll up and down. What I want is to stop that from happening.

Comment: Please correct me if understood it in a wrong way. You want to change the row color when user is scrolling the DataGrid depending on row cell value. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Linker No, what I want is that when the DataGrid is created the rows are colored and shouldn't change no matter what after that. What I meant with the values is that in the DataGrid, a column shows values. In this case it is seconds, and if the a cell in that column shows, for example, 25 seconds the whole row of that cell is colored red. So the color should not move when I'm scrolling. It should stay on the row that has 25 seconds for example. And I have no clue why the colours are all moving around when I'm scrolling...

Comment: So, you want a sticky red row. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Linker I guess you could say so. I just don't want the color to move around and stick to its original row when I'm scrolling.